# How to display sub-category from one category? New .phtml for left navigation

Tags: navigation, phtml

How to display category from one category? I created a new file .phtml But I do not know how to write code in phtml file. I watched Google and other issues, but have not found a friendly solution. Please, help.
[image: screenshot]
I have this code.[image: screenshot]

Comment: You might want to explain a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to create a block on the left. In it will be displayed subcategory from one main category. He will always be displayed

Answer (score 1):

You write code in phtml the same way you write html file.
If you wanna to get the category children  from a specific category, you might write something like this:

```
$childrenCategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',$parentCategoryId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level',$parentCategoryLevel+1);
```

You can do this as well

```
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();
$childrenCategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                                    'in'=> $subcats));
```

At the phtml it should be this way

```
<?php
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();
$childrenCategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                                    'in'=> $subcats));
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($childrenCategoryCollection as $childCat) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $childCat->getName()?></li>
<?php endforeach?>
</ul>
```